# what does this command does in bash: ,_,( ){ ,_,| ,_,&};,_,

Tags: bash, fork

`,_,( ){ ,_,| ,_,&};,_,`

I am not sure what it means...

Looks like a bash command but it might be s bash shell directive or something 
would appreciate if someone can help understand this. It killed my bash when I ran it.

Answer (score 15):

It's a [fork bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb); it will spawn a (potentially) infinite number of processes, until your system runs out of resources (and usually becomes inoperable).

It defines the function named `,_,`, which runs itself (recursion), and piping the output to itself. The last `,_,` is needed to start off the thing.

Formatted, and with `,_,` replaced by `fun`, it looks like:

```
fun() {
   fun | fun &
};
fun
```

Every invocation of `fun` will spawn 2 more invocations of `fun`. The `&` starts the processes in the background (rate of process increase is *exponential*).

It's a variant of the [better known](http://tattoospin.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/awesome-fork-bomb-tattoo-from-alex-godair-from-north-street-tattoo-in-normal-il-hack-the-planet.jpg) `:() { :|: & };:`

There are ways to prevent your system from crashing, though; for example in Linux you can edit `/etc/security/limit.conf` & set the maximum number of processes for a user. Other systems have other (usually similar) methods.

Running a fork bomb and crashing your system seems to be something of a rite of passage for UNIX users; it teaches you:

1. The importance of imposing resource limits of processes;
2. that copying & executing commands you do not understand from untrusted sources (eg. the internet) is not a good idea