# Dropbox fs.inotify error

Tags: dropbox

I frequently get the following Dropbox error. The error message's proposal fixes  the error, but  I'm trying to figure out what it's doing to my system, and perhaps if there is a root cause at play.

> Unable to monitor entire Dropbox folder hierarchy. Please run
>
> ```
> echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf; sudo sysctl -p`
> ```
>
> and restart Dropbox to fix the problem.

Comment: I'd say this question would be a better fit for [su], but I'm afraid you'd lose your bounty, so maybe migrating it now isn't the best idea.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Note**: I strongly encourage you to actually *DO* the steps and not just *read* them if you want to learn about Linux!

---

If I type `apropos inotify` in a shell to see which manpage are about "inotify" I get these results:

```
$ apropos inotify
inotify (7)          - monitoring filesystem events
inotify_add_watch (2) - add a watch to an initialized inotify instance
inotify_init (2)     - initialize an inotify instance
inotify_init1 (2)    - initialize an inotify instance
inotify_rm_watch (2) - remove an existing watch from an inotify instance
upstart-file-bridge (8) - Bridge between Upstart and inotify
```

`apropos` finds manpages. `apropos` is your friend. Remember `apropos`.

The first one looks promising, so lets try opening that with `man inotify`. You should now get the documentation of `ifnotify`. It says:

```
NAME
    inotify - monitoring filesystem events

DESCRIPTION
    The  inotify API provides a mechanism for monitoring filesystem events.
    Inotify can be used to monitor individual files, or to monitor directo‐
    ries.   When  a  directory is monitored, inotify will return events for
    the directory itself, and for files inside the directory.
```

So now we've learned what `inotify` roughly does. Let's see if it also has something useful to
say about your error.

We can search in manpages by pressing `/<term><enter>`. So lets try: `/max_user_watches<enter>` That brings us to this section:

```
   /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
          This specifies an upper limit on the number of watches that  can
          be created per real user ID.
```

The `/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches` file is the same as the `fs.inotify.max_user_watches` setting in `/etc/sysctl.conf`. They're just two different ways to access the same Linux kernel parameter.

You can press `q` to exit.

I can see what the *current* value is by using:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
524288
```

or:

```
$ sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288
```

They both use the same underlying value in the Linux kernel.

Note that this value is actually five times *larger* than what Dropbox recommends! This is on my Ubuntu 15.10 system.

So now we have learned that:

1. `inotify` is a Linux system to monitor changes to files and directories.
2. That we can set how many files or directories a user is allowed to watch simultaneously.
3. That Dropbox gives the error "Unable to monitor entire Dropbox folder hierarchy".

From this information, It seems to be the case that Dropbox is unable to watch enough files and directories for changes because the `fs.inotify.max_user_watches` is too low.

What I recommend is:

1. Check the `/etc/sysctl.conf` with any text editor as root. Make sure there are no `fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000` lines here. If there are, remove them.
2. Reboot the system to restore the default value.
3. Check what the value of `fs.inotify.max_user_watches` is as described above.
4. Double that by running `sudo echo 'fs.inotify.max_user_watches=XXX' >> /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf`. You don't need to reboot after this change.
5. Hope this error is now fixed. Time will tell. If not, try doubling the value again.

   - If that doesn't fix it, there *may* be another problem, or maybe you just need to increase it *even more*. It depends a bit on what the default value is for your system.

**Note**: Newer versions of systemd no longer load the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file, it will only load files from the `/etc/sysctl.d/` directory. Using a file in the `/etc/sysctl.d` directory *should* already be supported by most Linux distros, so I recommend you use that for future-proofing.

---

If you're wondering "why is there a limit in the first place?" then consider what would happen if a program would watch a million files. Would that still work? And what about a billion? 10 billion? 10 trillion? etc.

At some point, your system will run out of resources and crash. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27197785/660921) on some "fun" ways to do that ;-)

Comment: Brilliant answer, thank you. However this isn't a permanent solution on Arch as `/etc/sysctl.conf` seems to be deprecated and the setting is lost on reboot. Add line to `/usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-default.conf` instead. See https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=193020

Comment: `/etc/sysctl.d/` is better than `/usr/lib/sysctl.d/` for this use case. From the [sysctl.d man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sysctl.d.5.html#CONFIGURATION_DIRECTORIES_AND_PRECEDENCE): “Files in /etc/ are reserved for the local administrator, who may use this logic to override the configuration files installed by vendor packages.”